# Purpose of extern Variable?

Tags: c, global-variables, terminology, extern

In c, it seems to me that everything written outside of a function is already 'extern'. 
When, then, exactly do you have to specify a variable as extern?

Does it have to do with definition vs declaration?

Also, is declaring a variable with extern necessary in order to access a variable defined in another file already?

Comment: Maybe read the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how

Comment: By using `extern`, you are telling the compiler that whatever follows it will be found (non-static) at link time.

Comment: and and `me that everything written outside of a function is already 'extern'.` how? it's only local to file in which it written.

Comment: But when you #include that file, you can access the variable, right?

Comment: yes you can access it. but make sure you have `extern` it in header file other wise multiple definition error cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [extern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable) extends the visibility to the whole program, by externing a variable we can use the variables anywhere in the program provided we know the declaration of them and the variable is defined somewhere.

Declarations of variables **at file scope** (Not in other files ) are **external** by default.

> In c, it seems to me that everything written outside of a function is
>   already 'extern'. When, then, exactly do you have to specify a
>   variable as extern?

this is most probably true for c `functions`
By default, the declaration and definition of a C function have “extern” prepended with them

For example have one file named `file1.c` and declared function lilke

```
int my_function();
```

There’s an `extern` present in the beginning which is hidden and the compiler treats it as below.

```
extern int my_function();
```

Therefore whenever we define a C function, an extern is present there in the beginning of the function definition.

For `C` variables

While defining a function, we can prepend it with extern without any issues. But it is not the case with **C variables**.

If we put the presence of `extern` in variable as default then the memory for them will not be allocated ever, they will be declared only. Therefore, we put `extern` explicitly for C variables when we want to declare them without defining them. `

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you would use `extern` variables.

I have a UART.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<string.h>
#include<UART.h>

int UART_Rcv(unsigned char* Rx_Str[], unsigned int len);

int status;

int UART_Rcv(unsigned char* Rx_Str[], unsigned int len)
{
    //Some code for implementation of UART receive.

    //set status value and return it, May be (SUCCESS or FAILURE?)
    return status;
}
```

Now I have a UART.h

```
 //header guard
 #ifndef __UART_H
 #define __UART_H

 //Some UART related macros

 extern int status;
 extern int UART_Rcv(unsigned char* Rx_Str[], unsigned int len);

 //other externs if any

 #endif
```

Now I have a main.c which is going to use the function and variable declared in UART.c

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<string.h>
#include<UART.h>

#define WIMP_OUT_N_GO_HOME     (0)

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char Received_String[30];

    //Some code and may be initialization of UART?

    //Flush the Received_String before using it
    UART_Rcv(Received_String, 10);

    //Some code

    return WIMP_OUT_N_GO_HOME;
}
```

When a variable is defined, the compiler allocates memory for that variable and possibly also initializes its contents to some value. When a variable is declared, the compiler requires that the variable be defined elsewhere. So By `extern`ing your `UART_Rcv()` function and the `status` variable, you hinted your compiler that those are defined outside of the functional block, or may be in a different source, like we did here. the definitions for those will be found at the linker time.

An external variable must be defined, exactly once, outside of any function

Comment: `extern int UART_Rcv(...`: here the `extern` keyword is not required.

Comment: `extern int UART_Rcv(...` -> `int UART_Rcv(...`. The `extern` keyword fron of a function prototype is a NOP.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: And, that is not compiler dependent. Right?

Comment: No, AFAIK it's not compiler dependent.